# Android Device Does not have option for : Android (Security Settings) Model : One plus 9 pro

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, device

I can not give permissions to android app,  In the developer options menu, there is only  USB debugging option is available.

Here are the Command line outputs,

```
  $ pm grant com.draco.resolutionchanger android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

 Exception occurred while executing 'grant':
 java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has     android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.
    at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:2186)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:2214)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermissionInternal(PermissionManagerService.java:1470)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:1452)
    at android.permission.PermissionManager.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManager.java:378)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2419)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:260)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:25770)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:970)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:854)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4818)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:8872)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1226)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1163)
```

Answer (score 2):

In developer settings on android enable "disabled permissions monitoring" and then turn "USB debugging" off and back on. After resetting your phone it should work.

From https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unable-to-grant-permissions-using-adb.3812658/page-2

(It did for me on one plus 9 and the same command)